# I am getting multiple headers and footers in word document, getting null in policy.GetFirstPageHeader() using NPOI

Tags: ms-word, header, npoi

I am getting multiple headers and footers in a Word document; I cannot differentiate the firstpage, default(odd), or even headers.

When I am trying to call `policy.GetFirstPageHeader()` I am getting a null value.

```
XWPFHeaderFooterPolicy policy = new XWPFHeaderFooterPolicy(document);

var headerList = document.HeaderList;
var footerList = document.FooterList;

var firstPageHeader = policy.GetFirstPageHeader();
var firstPageFooter = policy.GetFirstPageFooter();

XWPFHeader header = policy.GetDefaultHeader();
XWPFHeader even = policy.GetEvenPageHeader();
XWPFHeader odd = policy.GetOddPageHeader();
```

I am getting null values. Can any one suggest how to differentiate headers in a Word document?

Comment: Open the document in the Word UI. Does it have the "Different First Page" option activated? If not, there is no First Page Header, so that would explain the null value. Same holds for even pages. The Default, on the other hand, should always be avaiable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var listOfheaders = new List<CT_HdrFtrRef>();
foreach (var par in document.Paragraphs)
{
var ParagraphsectPr = (CT_P)par.GetType().GetField("paragraph", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic).GetValue(par);

 if (ParagraphsectPr.pPr.sectPr != null)
{
foreach (var headerref in ParagraphsectPr.pPr.sectPr.headerReference)
 {
   listOfheaders.Add(headerref);
 }
 }
}

                foreach (var list in listOfheaders)
                {                    
                    var relatedPart = document.GetRelationById(list.id);
                    XWPFHeader hdr = null;
                    if (relatedPart != null && relatedPart is XWPFHeader)
                    {
                        hdr = (XWPFHeader)relatedPart;
                    }
                    // Assign it
                    ST_HdrFtr type = list.type;
                    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(hdr.Text))
                    {
                        if (type == ST_HdrFtr.first)
                        {
                            firstPageHeadr = hdr;
                        }
                        else if (type == ST_HdrFtr.even)
                        {
                            evenPageHeader = hdr;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            defaultHeader = hdr;
                        }
                    }                   
                }
```